# show data with shipmentdate bigger than today

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to pulling data for all shipments with shipmentdate greater than todays date. However, I cant figure out an easy conversion of the format of the nvarchar, i get a out of range value error when trying to run this:

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_CT_RAW_ARCHIVE_TBL
where SHIPMENTDATE > GETDATE()
```

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a nvarchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Do you mean that SHIPMENTDATE is varchar? If yes, why?

Comment: You need to show examples of what the values look like.  But really, fix the data, so you are using  types correctly.

Comment: you should not be storing dates as text. The `datetime` column type exists for very good reasons, such as avoiding this kind of silly problem. Date formats are for use by humans, not computers.

Comment: Could you show us example dates?

Comment: The format of shipmentdate col is : nvarchar(255),null , example of data is "18/07/2018"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * 
from dbo.BAS_CT_RAW_ARCHIVE_TBL
where convert(date, SHIPMENTDATE, 103) > GETDATE()
```

To see how to use `convert` with non-standard dates see **[this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp)**.

Further consideration: use proper datatypes for columns, i.e. don't store dates as strings, but as `date` datatype - it will prevent you from having such problems.

Comment: You are my hero, that one seems to work! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Robert Then you should accept the answer (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

according to your data format that got from comment below should work

```
 select * from dbo.BAS_CT_RAW_ARCHIVE_TBL
    where CONVERT(date, SHIPMENTDATE, 103) > convert(date, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Gives me the error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Changing a implicit cast/convert that fails to an explicit cast/convert is not going to solve the fact that the cast/convert fails. So this answer adds nothing.

Comment: @PeterB i thought it is varchar type but store date values so i response that onw

Comment: The question contains no source data (yet) so making guesses about how it is formatted is pointless.

Comment: The format of shipmentdate col is : nvarchar(255),null

Comment: @Robert that's just the column type. We would need to see the actual format of the date string (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd or whatever you use) stored in the column. But like everyone said above, the best thing to do would be to change your shipmentdate to a `datetime` column (instead of `nvarchar`), then you won't have these kinds of entirely avoidable problems. Dates are dates, they are not text. You only output them into a specific text format when you want to show them to a human being, and then you format it according to the particular cultural conventions that the human is used to.

Comment: The format of shipmentdate col is : nvarchar(255),null , example of data is "18/07/2018"

Comment: @Robert in that case `Convert(date,SHIPMENTDATE,103)` should work, assuming the date is in the same format inside every row.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin `Convert(Varchar(50)` makes no sense. You want to convert it to a date, so you can compare it to the date object produced by GETDATE(). At the moment your code tries to convert a string into a shorter string, which is pointless for this purpose.

Comment: check the answer i was not in desk so late @Robert

Comment: those guys given me down vote i think you will remove it , as the beginning of question data format was unknown and i mentioned it in my post that it may work you need conversion and @ADyson did great job by continuing conversion with R he found it so thanks to  him ,

Comment: @Robert i can expect upvote from you as my post begin to solve yor problem

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin now your answer makes sense I have upvoted it. Right from the beginning it was clear the column was nvarchar, and so it's unclear why you wrote code to convert it to varchar. And in any case without any context it's obvious that you shouldn't compare a string to a date.